# Removing splash screen from UWP app in Fall Creators Update (FCU)

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, splash-screen

I read in some article regarding **new Fall Creators Update SDK** that it is now possible to develop apps **without splash screens** for faster loading times.

My question is, how do we eliminate a splash screen when starting up an app? Where is the documentation for the changes to make to the app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open your *Package.appxmanifest* file from your main project and add `a:Optional="true"` to

```
<uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" a:Optional="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5" />
```

However, you will still need to provide a *splash* image because `a:Optional`

> Specifies whether an app should be launched without a splash screen.
>   If true, the splash screen will not be shown if the app can launch
>   fast enough. If there is a delay in the app launch time, the splash
>   screen will be shown. If false, the splash screen will always be
>   shown.

Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap-splashscreen) for more information.

Comment: You should add namespace **a** to `IgnorableNamespaces`, otherwise you won't be able to compile with .net native.

Comment: @JetChopper hmm I didn't need to add it but it still compiles with .Net Native. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I don't remember what the error was but adding to `IgnorableNamespaces` cured the problem. Just in case if someone will stuck on it.

Answer (score 5):

Simply comment out the splash screen in the manifest file.

file: `package.appmanifest`

```
<!-- <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" /> -->
```

Comment: It will use the default color white as the splash screen

Comment: In some cases it's a better option than the forced splash screen logo