# UWP Customized Splash Screen Sample

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, splash-screen

I want to create a splash screen in UWP. I want do more than just center an image in the screen. I thought it would be a lot more straight forward. I saw these articles:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh868191(v=win.10)

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Splash-Screen-in-Universal-42c0b57a

When I first opened up this sample, I thought that it worked... But, it doesn't actually do anything. It's actually just a furphy. If you look carefully at the screen, it actually just shows an image (defined in the manifest) for a second or two as the app is starting up, and then when the app is loaded, it switches to the extended screen with a progress ring. I've seen samples where people turn on the splash screen image, but that's not want I need to achieve. Part of the problem is that UWP app startup time is terrible even on fast machines. Even blank apps with nothing in them take several seconds to start up.

Is there a UWP sample floating around that actually a) cuts out the splash image from the manifest, and b) allows us to replace it with something else?

Note: **I do not wish to remove the splash screen. I want to customize it.**

Comment: You can make the splash screen optional, but if the load time is higher than expected it will show up..(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201701/removing-splash-screen-from-uwp-app-in-fall-creators-update-fcu) After making it optional you can use your custom page which has the loading animation as the entry point of the application.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I don't want to remove the splash screen.

Comment: @Pratyay , there's no point in displaying the splash screen after the app has been initialized. The only reason someone would put a splash screen in an app is for the initialization process.

Comment: Usually you would load your `MainPage` right away which would have the initialization logic right ? Instead of loading the the "Heavy" `MainPage` directly you can show an intermediate loading page (your custom splashscreen) which would then navigate to your MainPage.

Answer (score 2):

The main splash screen (centered splash screen image defined in the `package.appxmanifest`) will always be displayed unless you make it [optional](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/11/making-uwp-splash-screen-optional/) - while even in this case it will be shown to the user when the app doesn't load immediately.

To make the splash screen optional, you have to open the manifest file as XML, add the following namespace declaration:

```
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5">
```

And then add the `uap5:optional` attribute to your splash screen:

```
<uap:SplashScreen ... uap5:Optional="true" />
```

You can implement an extended splash screen, which is described in the articles you linked. If you postpone all initialization for the extended splash screen, it is quite likely that the optional default splash screen will not display at all.

However, although the samples only show the same image with progress ring, you can put any content you want on the extended splash screen, you are in full control of it because it is a normal `Page`.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that it's not possible to show a custom splash screen while the app is starting up. You have an option to display an image, and that is it. Essentially, that's pathetic. Even on Android it's possible to define more than just an image on the splash screen. I really think that Microsoft needs to fix this. Do you know of any requests for this anywhere?

Comment: I guess the larger issue is the actual startup time itself. The splash image displays for a couple of seconds even on a really fast machine. I guess that is the bigger problem than the lack of ability to customize the splash screen. I'm guessing that the UWP team didn't bother changing the system because they figured they'd eventually fix the startup time.

Comment: how would I "postpone all initialization" ? I'm not doing anything in the initialization. The startup time is just because UWP apps are really slow at starting up.

Comment: You can put the request on UserVoice and in the Feedback hub. I also agree that this should be improved, to be able to define a layout in similar manner to the adaptive cards and tiles

Comment: The startup time should definitely be better in release mode, in debug there is a major delay because the debugger must be attached

Comment: The apps will probably launch faster once the OneCore and Composable Shell initiatives are in place. I think the slowness is caused by the fact that the "sandbox" takes time to be constructed in the "legacy" destkop environment

Comment: I think you're right. But, actually, I think compiling for .NET Native makes the app startup time negligible. So, I guess it's a question of whether it's even necessary to have a splash screen... I think I need to reword my question.

Comment: I do think about one reason in favor of splash screen. Suppose an app does perform a lot of tasks on startup, like getting some data from a web service - in this case showing the splash screen lets the user know something is actually happening. I remember, when I tried launching Chrome / Firefox / IE on my sister's very old computer. Clicking the browser shortcuts did nothing, so after a minute I tried again and then again. And after excruciatingly long time all the windows showed up at once. So if the system can launch the apps splash fast, the user at least knows something is going on :-D

Comment: That's a fair call. But, there's no issue with this. We can easily just navigate to any normal page in UWP after the runtime has started up. The problem is that when the app is starting up it takes a couple of seconds to load the runtime and that's where you are forced to display the splash image. I guess really, I need to edit the question at the beginning. Really, what I need to do is compile with .NET native and forget about the splash image. It's just not useful because it will always be too fast for the user to see in .NET Native mode.