# How to add extended splash to windows template studio?

Tags: uwp, windows-template-studio

I'm using `windows template studio` to create my app, and want to add a `extended splash screen` refered [Display a splash screen for more time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-a-customized-splash-screen).

For the code write in `App.xaml.cs` in windows template studio, they use `ActivationService`. I don't know how to add the `extended splash` properly.

Is any one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to add extended splash to windows template studio?

You could try to edit `ActivationService` like the follow

```
public async Task ActivateAsync(object activationArgs)
{
    if (IsInteractive(activationArgs))
    {
        // Initialize things like registering background task before the app is loaded
        await InitializeAsync();

        if ((activationArgs as LaunchActivatedEventArgs).PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
        {
            bool loadState = ((activationArgs as LaunchActivatedEventArgs).PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated);
            ExtendedSplash extendedSplash = new ExtendedSplash((activationArgs as LaunchActivatedEventArgs).SplashScreen, loadState);
            var rootFrame = new Frame();
            rootFrame.Content = extendedSplash;
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (Window.Current.Content == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            Window.Current.Content = _shell?.Value ?? new Frame();
        }
    }

    await HandleActivationAsync(activationArgs);
    _lastActivationArgs = activationArgs;


    if (IsInteractive(activationArgs))
    {
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();

        // Tasks after activation
        await StartupAsync();
    }
}
```

**ExtendedSplash**

```
void DismissExtendedSplash()
{
    // Navigate to mainpage
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ShellPage));
    // Place the frame in the current Window
    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Nico, I found the default splash still exist before the extended splash, see the repo: https://github.com/hupo376787/SplashTest.git. How to totally remove the default splash?

Comment: It is by-design, ExtendedSplash will not replace the default splash, it just extend the default splash display time, and for the uniting the ui, please make sure the default splash similar as extend splash. Please refer this code [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SplashScreen).

Comment: Ok, got it. I used a trick way to avoid this. First, make SplashScreen.scale-200.png file all transparent. Second, open "Package.appxmanifest", set the background color field of the Splash Screen section, set the color similar to the extended splash. Done!

Comment: The default splash screen can be removed since Fall Creators Update SDK. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201701/removing-splash-screen-from-uwp-app-in-fall-creators-update-fcu/47201913#47201913

Answer (score 1):

There are some problem with the above answer:

1, can lead to the inability to handle other services, such as Toast.

2, causing the theme settings to be invalid, can only follow the system theme. This is my solution:

```
 if ((activationArgs as IActivatedEventArgs).Kind == ActivationKind.Launch)
 {
     if ((activationArgs as LaunchActivatedEventArgs).PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
     {
       bool loadState = ((activationArgs as LaunchActivatedEventArgs).PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated);
       ExtendedSplash extendedSplash = new ExtendedSplash((activationArgs as LaunchActivatedEventArgs).SplashScreen, loadState);
       var rootFrame = new Frame();
       rootFrame.Content = extendedSplash;
       Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
      }
  }
```

Remove "InitializeAsync()" from "ActivationService".Add to ExtendedSplash.xaml.cs. Here,in order to avoid the window being activated when the picture is loading, write it in the "ImageOpened" event.

```
private async void ExtendedSplashImage_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Window.Current.Activate();
     if (splash != null)
     {
        splash.Dismissed += new TypedEventHandler<SplashScreen, Object>(DismissedEventHandler);

        splashImageRect = splash.ImageLocation;

        PositionImage();
        PositionRing();
     }
     rootFrame = new Frame();

     //place it here
     await InitializeAsync();
 }

 private async Task InitializeAsync()
 {
      // 
      await ThemeSelectorService.InitializeAsync();           

      DismissExtendedSplash();

      // Must be behind “DismissExtendedSplash()”
      await ThemeSelectorService.SetRequestedThemeAsync();
 }
```

Now,finished.In fact, there are still some problems, English is not good, so I will not say it. All of the above are translated using translation software.